# Using preg_replace to colorize things

Tags: php, codeigniter, preg-replace

I have a script that pulls data from a database, and based on the info pulled, I want to colorize it and stuff

I want to make it so that if the data pulled is

```
&cTe&bst
```

It replaces it with

```
<font style="color:#F55">Te</font><font style="color:#5FF">st</font>
```

But also I need to make sure I can add more and more to it.

I'd also like it to be a function so I can simply do

```
$this->colorize('&cTe&bst');
```

I'm using CodeIgniter

Comment: What is `&cTe&bst` supposed to mean? What are the ampersands for? What is the `c` and `b` that you left out in the output string?

Comment: It's for a minecraft thing, in minecraft if you put &c before text, it turns it into a color, and I want to be able to use that on a site for this project since the data will be pulled with that.

Comment: Does the colour style exist until the next `&`?

Comment: I think you need to give us background on the color scheme. Its important because I am sure there is no built in code igniter function that knows this meaning you need to essentially write a function that parses the string and checks that for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
function colorize($in)
{
    $Colors = array(
        "b" => "#000",
        "w" => "#FFF",
        "g" => "#AAA"
    );

    $in = "<span>" . $in;

    foreach($Colors as $Prefix => $Color)
    {
        $in = str_replace( "&" . $Prefix, "</span><span style='color: " . $Color . "'>", $in );
    }

    $in .= "</span>";
    return $in;
}
```

Simple and easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `<font>` tag repeatedly like that, use a `<span>` with a style sheet.

```
<span class="blue">Te</span><span class="red">st</span>

.blue {
    font-color: #3F1515;
}

.red {
    font-color: #153F3F;
}
```

This will make it more readable and make the HTML a lot smaller in size as well.

For your regex try `&.(.*?)(?=&|$)` http://regexr.com?30qid

Answer (score 0):

No need to use `preg_replace`, just `explode` the string by `&` and go from there:

```
$colors = array('c' => '#F55', 'b' => '#5FF');

$str = '&cTe&bst';

foreach (explode('&', $str) as $text)
{
    $colorCode = $text[0];
    $actualText = substr($text, 1);
    echo '<span style="color:' . $colors[$colorCode] . '>' . $actualText . '</span>';
}
```

DISCLAIMER: Untested…

Comment: For this one I get an error "Uninitialized string offset: 0" for "$colorCode = $text[0];"

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't test it, probably better to explode the string, `var_dump` the result and see how to process it from there...